# Numerical Convergence of Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: numerical-methods, quadrature

So I am implementing the trapezoidal rule as my choice of quadrature. Most functions seem to be second order convergence except for two:

$$ f(x) = e^{cos(x)} - .1cos(x), \quad x \in [-7, -2] $$

The loglog plot of $f(x)$ of error vs $dx$ size is

[image]

where the red dashed line is a line with slope 2. I imagine the plot looks this way since we need smaller time step size to get better results, but I am wondering $\textbf{why does step size need to reach some size to get second order convergence}$.

The second function giving me weird behavior is

$$ g(x) = cos(e^x)  - x^2sin(x) - x, \quad x \in [-5, 5]$$
The loglog plot of $g(x)$ of error vs $dx$ size is

[image]

where the red dashed line is again a line with slope 2. For this one, I assume there is some inequality the derivatives of $g$ and step size must satisfy to keep second order convergence but am left wondering $\textbf{why does the order of convergence "disappear" as step size decreases}$.

Comment: Such phenomena can be caused by floating point arithmetic; these cause the theoretical order of convergence to appear only in a certain bounded range, and also causes the error to eventually worsen for very small step sizes. But it seems like that should happen at still smaller step sizes than $10^{-3}$. On the flip side, in the second graph, the ostensibly weird results at *large* step sizes are not really surprising. They indicate that not all of your errors have the same sign so that for certain larger step sizes you have cancellations that give you an unexpectedly good result.

Comment: (In fact really the second graph is exactly what you should expect for second order convergence, a line of slope 2 *for small enough $\Delta x$* and pretty much anything at all for larger $\Delta x$. It is the first graph that is peculiar.)

Comment: So these are sort of the hand wavy explanations I was going over in my head, but was wondering if there was a mathematical way to show why these phenomenon were happening.

Comment: The first graph can be explained in terms of the error being a sum of a decreasing function of $h$ and an increasing function of $h$, the former arising from floating point and the latter arising from discretization. This is of course for $h$ in some range $(0,h_{max})$. People around here can do that, though I would argue that you should ask this question more specifically. In the second graph there is nothing to explain: for that function the correction terms are too large when $h>0.02$ or so, so that retaining only the leading order term of the error is not accurate.

Comment: Thank you Ian. I now understand the behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first graph is showing a slowdown of convergence at small step sizes. This is a typical feature of floating point arithmetic for things like definite integrals. At even smaller step sizes you will start to see the error increase as the step size is decreased. Mathematically this can be understood by estimating the total error as a function of $\Delta x$. You will find that there is a term that decreases with $\Delta x$ that arises from floating point and another that increases with $\Delta x$ that arises from discretization. I find it a bit peculiar to see this effect when the number of subintervals is only 5000, however.

The second graph is showing erratic behavior at larger step sizes and the predicted second order convergence at small step sizes. This is basically what the theory predicts: for sufficiently small step sizes you should see second order behavior, but for larger step sizes the correction terms (which are, for smooth functions, proportional to 3rd and higher derivatives) are too large to be neglected. In this example the $\cos(e^x)$ term has huge higher derivatives in the range, say, $[3,5]$.